# Teradata DBS state is 7: System is operational without PEs - Sessions are not allowed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, teradata

I have installed Vmware teradata player TDExpress14.10_Sles11_40GB on Ubuntu.

I am getting "DBS state is 7: System is operational without PEs - Sessions are not allowed" when using "pdestate -a";

I found some solutions related with vproc manager like;

http://teradata-suresh.blogspot.com/2011/02/when-you-may-get-10065-wsa-e-host.html

But they are windows based. I don't know how to start vprocmanager in linux wm.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the vprocmanager is a windows application from a time where the TD Express was installed natively on your Windows. - looooong time ago.

As of now you have to use the same tools like Admins in the productive environment. You should either try /etc/init.d/tpa [stop|start] or /usr/pde/bin/tpareset.

Because there will be a reason why the RDBMS doesn't startup properly it's worth to check the log file /var/log/messages.

You can check the syntax and the other tools in the documentation in the book "Utilities" (1102).

Horst

Comment: VProcManager is not Windows based, it's run from the Database Window, in Linux it's started using `xdbw`. Of course the OP should know what happened before setting the PE to *Online* again.